# Mostrar tablas del usuario usando sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server

Tengo la siguiente sentencia para conectarme a la base de datos:

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:ip -U usuario -P password
```

¿Cómo puedo saber cuales son las tablas creadas por ese usuario y su estructura?

He intentado con

```
select name from sysobjects ..
```

Pero no he tenido el resultado deseado.

Comment: ¿Que versión de SQL Server? Las tablas `sys*` se mantienen por compatibilidad pero se recomienda usar las vistas de sistemas.

Comment: 2016 gracias  por contestas

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes saber es quién es el dueño de la tabla, no necesariamente quién la creó. Supongamos que el usuario es `dbo`, para obtener los nombres de las tablas y la estructura de cada una, puedes apoyarte en las vistas:

- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)
- [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNAS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Ejemplo, filtrando por el Owner `dbo`:

```
SELECT  T.TABLE_CATALOG,
    T.TABLE_SCHEMA,
    T.TABLE_NAME,
    C.ORDINAL_POSITION, 
    C.COLUMN_NAME, 
    C.DATA_TYPE, 
    C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH, 
    C.IS_NULLABLE, 
    C.NUMERIC_PRECISION,
    C.NUMERIC_SCALE
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES T
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        ON C.TABLE_CATALOG = T.TABLE_CATALOG
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = T.TABLE_NAME
    WHERE T.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo'
    ORDER BY T.TABLE_CATALOG,
        T.TABLE_SCHEMA,
        T.TABLE_NAME,
        C.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Aquí un [fiddle](http://rextester.com/KUTTQ82726)